# Backup to a point in time

Tags: sql-server, backup

To be clear from the outset this question is about backing up a database to a specific point in time, not restoring to a point in time.  The scenario is this: we have a consultant working on implementation of a new payroll system who wants historical data from our time keeping system for a given pay period for parallel testing.  He would like to restore production data to a test database at one date in time, and then later do another restore from a second date.  We do full and transactional backups, but have nothing going back beyond a week, and of course he's looking for something older than we have.

1. Is it possible to **back up** to a specific date?
2. Is there a function similar to `STOPAT` when doing backups?
3. Failing a backup is there some other method such as replication, copy, etc. that could achieve this result?

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I thought I'd ask anyway.  What I've suggested to him is that he waits until I have a complete two week pay period that I can restore from and I've extended our backups out a few weeks to cover this.  Hopefully that will be the simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

You are correct.

> what I've suggested to him is that he waits until I have a complete two week pay period that I can restore from and I've extended our backups out a few weeks to cover this.

Again, correct.

Comment: Thanks!  Definitely nice to get a second opinion.